# How to convert F4F file to MP4?

Tags: adobe

We know F4F is Adobe's fragmented MP4 file format for *HTTP Dynamic Streaming*. A tool called *F4F Packager* could convert an F4V file to several F4F files and a manifest file(F4M).

My question is, how to convert such F4F files back to an F4V or MP4 file?

Comment: I'd have more interest in a tool that would capture these streams.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We finally found a simple method to merge & convert **.f4f files -> .flv file**, in which only 'mdat' box is usefull. Here is a the php code:

```
<?php
  function ReadInt24($str, $pos)
    {
      return intval(bin2hex(substr($str, $pos, 3)), 16);
    }

  function ReadInt32($str, $pos)
    {
      return unpack("N", substr($str, $pos, 4))[1];
    }

  echo "\nKSV Adobe HDS Downloader\n\n";
  $flvHeader        = hex2bin("464c5601050000000900000000");
  $firstVideoPacket = true;
  $prevTagSize      = 4;
  $fragCount        = 0;

  isset($argv[1]) ? $baseFilename = $argv[1] : $baseFilename = "";
  $baseFilename ? $outputFile = "$baseFilename.flv" : $outputFile = "Joined.flv";
  while (true)
    {
      if (file_exists("$baseFilename" . $fragCount + 1 . ".f4f"))
          $fragCount++;
      else
          break;
    }
  echo "Found $fragCount fragments\n";
  $flv = fopen("$outputFile", "wb");
  fwrite($flv, $flvHeader, 13);

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $fragCount; $i++)
    {
      $frag = file_get_contents("$baseFilename$i.f4f");
      preg_match('/(.{4})mdat[\x08\x09\x12]/i', $frag, $mdat, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
      $fragLen = ReadInt32($mdat[1][0], 0) - 8;
      $frag    = substr($frag, $mdat[1][1] + 8, $fragLen);
      $pos     = 0;
      while ($pos < $fragLen)
        {
          $packetType  = $frag[$pos];
          $packetSize  = ReadInt24($frag, $pos + 1);
          $packetTS    = ReadInt24($frag, $pos + 4);
          $totalTagLen = 11 + $packetSize + $prevTagSize;
          if (($packetType == "\x08" && $packetSize > 4) or ($packetType == "\x09" && $packetSize > 40) or ($packetType == "\x09" && $firstVideoPacket))
            {
              if ($packetType == "\x09" && $firstVideoPacket)
                  $firstVideoPacket = false;
              fwrite($flv, substr($frag, $pos, $totalTagLen), $totalTagLen);
            }
          $pos += $totalTagLen;
        }
    }

  fclose($flv);
  echo "Finished\n";
?>
```

Comment: What did you make exactly? You wrote an header then merged only the mdat section?

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. Firstly there is no hex2bin function, the ReadInt32 function is invalid. I fixed all of these but still had a problem. I think my file is a 64bit mdat fragment as the first 4 character before mdat are 00 00 00 01 which obviously is not the size of the mdat.

Comment: The regex needs the s modifier: (.{4})mdat[\x08\x09\x12]/is

Comment: Enclose `$fragCount + 1` in parentheses to avoid bad handling of certain file names containing numbers.

Comment: We can do better than PHP.

Comment: It works for me after some changes. My fragment file has multiple fragments in one file. Initially the audio is broken but in the condition packetSize need to be greater than zero. After this my flv file was perfect =D thanks!

Answer (score 10):

A more comprehensive answer is available here : https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/blob/master/AdobeHDS.php.

The serious stuff happens [around line 1046](https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/blob/master/AdobeHDS.php#L1046).
This script handles more cases that the current top answer. I won't post the whole script here since it's a bit long.

Alas, it's a PHP script too, though I may need to rewrite this in Java in a couple of weeks. If so, I'll post a link to the Java rewrite when it's done.

Comment: Using the script worked for me: `php AdobeHDS.php --fragments Seg1-Frag` (my f4f files were: `Seg1-Frag1`, `Seg2-Frag2`, etc.)

Comment: Using the HDS Link Detector add-on in FireFox makes working with this script much easier.  I let the add-on generate the proper command, paste it into the console, and run it this way.

Answer (score 0):

livestreamer and youtube-dl both support HDS streams. Here's an example of livestreamer:

```
$ livestreamer -O 'hds://radio_chym-lh.akamaihd.net/z/KIT967_1@183249/manifest.f4m' 48k >out.m4a
```

This is an internet radio station. For video, only a change in `48k` and the file extension of `out.m4a` should be necessary.