# How to convert several f4f fragments to 1 mp4 file?

Tags: mp4, video-processing

I realize this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293671/how-to-convert-f4f-file-to-mp4), however I'm wondering if anyone can offer more simplistic instructions? I think I could be described as a relatively advanced computer user however I have no experience with assembling and disassembling media files.

Thanks in Advance,
N

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate, for more user friendly answers, perhaps SO is not the right place, answers with code are IHMO best SO answers so try on other forums example : http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/342430-F4F-capturing-converting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed stuff for Windows users:
php.exe (available with EasyPHP)
PHP script https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/blob/master/AdobeHDS.php
Program for renaming several files AF5 Rename http://www.fauland.com/af5.htm

Procedure:
Open the browser cache folder (for Chrome in Windows 7: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile \Cache);
Open the web page with the streaming video;
Look at the cache folder, you now see new files of ~ 1,5 MB created in short intervals;
Copy those files to the folder where resides php.exe;
Copy AdobeHDS.php to the same folder;
Rename files with AF5 Rename from 1.f4f to xxx.f4f (with counter 1-999);
Open dos prompt and go to the php folder and prompt

```
php AdobeHDS.php
```

The script join the fragments in joined.flv file.

This is it